# CloudWatch alarams using terraform for load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to create cloudwatch alarams for LB using terraform using below code. I am getting an error
An argument named "alb_arn_suffix" is not expected here.

here is the sample code which i am using.

```
   resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "this" { 
      alarm_name          = "alb-alarams"
      alarm_description   = "unhealthy"
      comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
      evaluation_periods  = 1
      threshold           = 1
      period              = 60
      unit                = "Count"
      namespace   = "ALB"
      metric_name = "UnHealthyHostCount"
      statistic   = "Sum"
      alb_arn_suffix = ["arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:124531745575:loadbalancer/app/alb- 
                        123/1cd382a00a565a8b"]
      alarm_actions = ["arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:124531745575:alb-alerts"]
      dimensions = {
     Name="ALB"
     Value="test"
     }
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are **several issues** with your `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm`.

1. `alb_arn_suffix` is invalid, thus error.
2. `dimensions` are also incorrect
3. `namespace` is sadly also wrong.

`UnHealthyHostCount` metric is part of [AWS/ApplicationELB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html) namespace, which has only two set of dimensions:

- TargetGroup, LoadBalancer
- TargetGroup, AvailabilityZone, LoadBalancer

Assuming that you would use first set, `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` would be something like the following:

```
 resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "this" { 
    alarm_name          = "alb-alarams"
    alarm_description   = "unhealthy"
    comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    evaluation_periods  = 1
    threshold           = 1
    period              = 60
    unit                = "Count"
    namespace   = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
    metric_name = "UnHealthyHostCount"
    statistic   = "Sum"
    alarm_actions = ["arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:124531745575:alb-alerts"]
    
    dimensions = {
       TargetGroup = aws_lb_target_group.lb-tg.arn_suffix
       LoadBalancer = aws_lb.lb.arn_suffix
   }   
}
```

You would have to substitute `aws_lb_target_group` and `aws_lb` for your values.

Comment: You made my weekend!!! Thanks alot Marcin this worked for me. How Can I create SNS topic and subscription and pass value dynamically to alaram_actions? Please advise.

Comment: @RudraG No problem. Glad it worked:-). I think it would be good if you could make new question specific to sns issues with relevant code and error messages.